# IPsec and pinging rightsubnets

Tags: iptables, ipsec, openswan

I have been racking my brain about this. I have openswan running and I have been able to get tunnels up. Unfortunately, when I try to ping computers on my right subnet, I am not able to get any response. I have an Amazon ec2 machine using Elastic ips. When I perform netstat -nr the gateway points to an ip address hence going through internet rather than the tunnel. Any pointers to resolving this?

```
leftsourceip=10.71.19.196 - {amazon elastic ip}
leftsubnets=10.71.19.196/32 {amazon elastic ip}
leftnexthop=%defaultroute
right=196.201.212.240
rightsubnets={196.201.214.95/32, 196.201.214.127/32,}
```

When pinging say 192.201.214.127 i get not response. Seems to default to a local ip gateway 192.169.16.1. Any idea on what I am doing wrong?